# SQLAlchemy self referencing table total combined list of attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this class structure:

```
class Employee(Base):
  __tablename__ = "employee"

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(255))
  parent_id = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey("employee.id"))

  children: Union[Column, List["Employee"]] = relationship(
    "Employee",
  )
  
  child_locations = association_proxy("children", 'id')
  
  @hybrid_property
  def all_child_and_parent_ids(self):
    return [child.id for child in self.child_locations] += [self.id]
```

As seen in the class structure, an employee can have child employees. I am attempting to create either a hybrid property or an association proxy that returns a list of IDs containing both the parent's ID and all of the children's IDs.

My current implementation of `all_child_and_parent_ids` is non-functional.

Ideal usage:

```
employee = Employee.query.get(employee_id)
print(employee.all_child_and_parent_ids)
# Expected output: [1, 23, 53]
```